# change mysql in case sensitive with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have hosted my application on third party hosting service where I don't have MYSQL console where I can change  **lower_case_table_names** variable.
In my php application SQL in mixed case (some time sample & some time SAMPLE)
I run query
`SELECT * FROM sample;`
It works fine but when I run this
`SELECT * FROM SAMPLE;`
It generate error that **#1146 - Table 'dbmma.SAMPLE' doesn't exist.**
How can I resolve it? and I think It is not feasible to change all SQL statement in my application.
Can I make change of SQL case-insensitive from PHPMYADMIN if yes then how?
Does storage engine affect on SQL case-sensitive? I have use **InnoDB**.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No. Case-sensitivity is a server setting; if you do not have access to the MySQL server configuration files (which it does not sound like you do), you cannot change it.

Comment: @eugen_sunic What are you expecting? No, nothing has changed. `lower_case_table_names` is still a server configuration option, and cannot be changed by users.